# IWebBrowser2 and move hosting window

Tags: c++, activex

I use `IWebBrowser2` to implement a GUI for my application. I have a custom frameless window which hosts `IWebBrowser2`. Javascript and `window.external` I use to communicate with the application.

My question is how to implement moving my host window (with `IWebBrowser2` of course)?
I draw a pseudo-Header in html and I need to detect mouse-down event (this is possible)
inside and detect mouse-move event after... and I don't know how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `IWebBrowser2` directly for this. Instead, use the Win32 API. You can get a `HWND` with `IWebBrowser2::get_HWND`. With that, it's easy to subclass its windowproc (via `SetWindowLong(GWL_WNDPROC)`) and intercept `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.

Comment: @vinnitu: please let us know whether it worked, so others don't have to experiment.

Comment: but I can get it such way http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752126(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @vinnitu: The article you linked is precisely the function I mentioned; what did you change between your last two comments to make it work?